# How to adjust the length of vertical dashed line between labels?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have used in my code:

```html
<span style="border-right-style: dashed; border-right-width:thin;">
```

Also, see attached image[image: I just want the line like as right side in image]

I just want the line like as right side in the image (3 dashes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the background image as follows.

```css
div {
  padding: 10px 50px;
}
.dashes {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 1px 14px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div class='dashes'>My text</div>
```

Or you can also use some small icon/thumbnail image of the 3 dashes to put it between your text.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a perfect solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **SVG** or small image of dased as icon images. These will help to put more designs of dashes.